# how can i change the options value with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jquery-mobile

Here is what seems to be bothering a lot of people (including me). When using the ng-options directive in AngluarJS to fill in the options for a `<select>` tag I cannot figure out how to set the value for an option. The documentation for this is really unclear

When I use ng-options inside select tag like this =>

`<select ng-options="cat as cat.name for cat in categories" ng-model="selectedCategory" name="category" class="form-control"></select>`

I get the options like this =>

`<option label="Mobile" value="object:5">Mobile</option>`

instead I want it like this =>

`<option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `track by cat.name`

```
<select ng-options="cat as cat.name for cat in categories track by cat.name" 
        ng-model="selectedCategory" name="category" class="form-control">
</select>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/me0vis?p=preview

Comment: Thanks you for up votes. Feel free to ask, and good luck in learning! :) @ChadidiAbdellah

Answer (score 0):

this should woork, you need to add "track by cat.name" like so :

```
<select ng-options="cat as cat.name for cat in categories track by cat.name" ng-model="selectedCategory" name="category" class="form-control"></select>
```